# How to pass list of object from JavaScript to Windows Runtime Component C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-runtime, uwp, winjs

I have created a WinRT component in C# which accepts a IEnumarable as a parameter

C#

```
public sealed class MyClass 
{
    public IEnumarable<DtoClass>  MyFunction(IEnumarable<DtoClass> properties) {

    return properties;
}
}
```

Java script

```
var Test=[];
for (var i = 0; i < res1.length; i++) 
{
    Test.push({ category_id: res1[i].category_id });
}
var Conncetion = WindowsRTSqlite.MyClass();
var result = Conncetion.MyFunction(Test);
```

I'm returning the same input parameters which I'm sending to MyFunction method but it's not return any result. I am not sure why this is not working. Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> How to pass list of object from JavaScript to Windows Runtime Component C#?

Actually the correct way is to serialize the collection to a json string and pass this string to the Windows Runtime Component. And deserialize the json string in the runtime component side for data dealing. After that return back the serialized json string to JavaScript uwp app. For how to serialize in JavaScript please reference [this class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON), for how to serialize in C# you can reference [this namespcase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.json). So your code on the JavaScript side may as follows:

```
 var Test = [];
 for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
     Test.push({ category_id: i });
 } 
 var Conncetion = RuntimeComponent1.MyClass();
 var Testserialation = JSON.stringify(Test);
 var resultnew = Conncetion.newFunction(Testserialation);
 var Testreturn = JSON.parse(resultnew);
```

And in windows runtime component:

```
public sealed class MyClass
{
   public string NewFunction(string jsonstring)
   {
       JsonArray entity= JsonArray.Parse(jsonstring); 
       return entity.ToString();           
   }
}
```

> I am not sure why this is not working.

According to your code snippet, you created an object array and trying to pass it to the runtime component as `IEnumarable<DtoClass>`. You passed an array, in my opinion you should be able receive it as an array. And I don't think object can be parsed to `DtoClass`  automatically. If you use a string or int array that can be recognized. For example , an int array:

```
 var newTest = [1, 2, 3, 4];
 var result2 = Conncetion.changeArray(newTest);
```

Code in component:

```
public int[] ChangeArray([ReadOnlyArray()] int[] input)
{
    int[] output =(int[])input.Clone();
    // Manipulate the copy.
    //   ...
    return output;
}
```

More details about passing arrays to a Windows Runtime Component please reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/passing-arrays-to-a-windows-runtime-component).